# Failed to execute goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.5:report-integration

Tags: jacoco-maven-plugin

It runs on different machine, but not on mine, i run it on docker on Mac, i've tried restarting docker and machine itself.

Below is my stacktrace of `mvn clean install -e`

```
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte (DataInputStream.java:267)
    at org.jacoco.core.internal.data.CompactDataInput.readBooleanArray (CompactDataInput.java:64)
    at org.jacoco.core.data.ExecutionDataReader.readExecutionData (ExecutionDataReader.java:150)
    at org.jacoco.core.data.ExecutionDataReader.readBlock (ExecutionDataReader.java:116)
    at org.jacoco.core.data.ExecutionDataReader.read (ExecutionDataReader.java:93)
    at org.jacoco.core.tools.ExecFileLoader.load (ExecFileLoader.java:60)
    at org.jacoco.core.tools.ExecFileLoader.load (ExecFileLoader.java:74)
    at org.jacoco.maven.ReportSupport.loadExecutionData (ReportSupport.java:89)
    at org.jacoco.maven.ReportITMojo.loadExecutionData (ReportITMojo.java:66)
    at org.jacoco.maven.AbstractReportMojo.executeReport (AbstractReportMojo.java:178)
    at org.jacoco.maven.AbstractReportMojo.execute (AbstractReportMojo.java:166)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

Comment: It could be that the JaCoCo execution data file is truncated - this has a propensity of occurring in a Docker environment running on MacOS. A rather illuminating discussion of the underlying causes can be found in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/901#issuecomment-508524494